# Как можно проверить работу авторизации в Linux для мониторинга в Zabbix?

Tags: linux, авторизация, active-directory, zabbix

Имеется проблема: при вводе сервера в домен, если отключить возможность авторизовываться под локальной УЗ есть вероятность того, что сервер вылетит из домена. Необходимо настроить мониторинг в Zabbix для доменной УЗ. Можно ли это сделать как-то через команды Linux? То есть на сервере проверить возможность авторизовываться под нужной УЗ? В Zabbix есть возможность делать проверки через SSH, но это немного не подходит, хотелось бы просто через UserParameter это организовать. Предлагали проверять логи авторизации, но и этот способ не подходит, так как сначала требуется авторизоваться на сервере, но это происходит вручную, а хотелось бы через какой-нибудь скрипт или средствами Zabbix это настроить.

Comment: Как вариант делать попытку подключения к локалхотсу по ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой. Для меня подошел вариант с авторизацией на sftp://localhost с помощью curl:

```
curl --insecure -u <user>:<pass> sftp://localhost
```

При удачной авторизации curl вернет список каталогов сервера, при неудачной - получим ошибку авторизации 67